# Normal derivative of a radial function over the boundary of a ball

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I have a radial function  $f(r)=r^4 $ where $r$ is the distance function. I have a ball $B_R=\{|x|<R\}$. I am trying  compute normal derivative of $f$ :  $\partial_n f=\nabla f\cdot n$ $\textbf{over the boundary $\partial B_R$}$   Here $n=(\frac{x_1}{R}, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{R})$ is the unit normal  vector. According to the definition, I got
$\partial_n f=\nabla f\cdot n= 4r^3\nabla r\cdot n=4r^3 (\frac{x_1}{r}, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{r})\cdot  (\frac{x_1}{R}, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{R}) =4R^3$. On the other hand, Over the boundary of $B_R$, $f(r)=r^4=R^4$ which is constant. In this case, the normal derivative over the boundary is zero.  There is something wrong here but I can't see it. So, I would be very grateful if you could clearly answer the normal derivative of a radial function at the boundary of a ball $B_R$={|x|=R}

Comment: The big problem here is that even in your statement of the question you did not specify IN WHAT DIRECTION you want the directional derivative. "Directional derivative" is meaningless unless it is followed by the phrase "in the direction" ...

Comment: I apologize. I mistakenly wrote directional derivative instead of Normal derivative in my question. To fix it, $\partial_n f$ denotes the normal derivative at the boundary.

Comment: OK, but if you have the normal firmly in your mind, you must realize that the second argument says nothing.

Comment: In polar coordinates, the normal derivative is $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$. So it is $0$ only if the function is a function of only the angular coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The first calculation is correct, the second is incorrect. The value of $u$ on $\partial B_R$ (constant or otherwise) gives you no information about $\partial_n u$ because $n$ is pointing normally to $\partial B_R$.

The fact $u$ is constant on $\partial B_R$ does tell us, however, that for each $x\in \partial B_R$, $\nabla u(x)\cdot v=0$ for all $v$ in the tangent space of $\partial B_R$ at $x$.